# how pass storagefile variable to backgroundtask?

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

I create  StorageFolder folder in mainpage :

```
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
        folderPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

Then i build Background Tasks and Triggers.
i want pass "StorageFolder folder" to background task...how do ??

Comment: What background task?

Comment: Use The value is there... backgroundtask with runtime component.............. public sealed class MyBackgroundTask1 : IBackgroundTask

Comment: What you want to do in your background task with this folder?

Comment: i want save file in folder path...